# TypeScript - how to inherit class and override lambda method

Tags: javascript, inheritance, typescript, lambda

I have an inherited class, and need the parent to have a virtual method, which is overridden in the child class. This method is called from the base constructor, and needs access to instance properties, so it needs to be a lambda function, so "this" is "_this".  The problem is, overriding a lambda method does not work for me like overriding a non-lambda does. Is this possible?  If not, I'd like to understand why.

Also, will "this" always be the same as "_this" when the method is only called from the constructor?

```
class Base {
    protected prop = null;
    constructor() {
        this.init();
        this.initLambda();
    }
    init() {
        console.log("Base init");
    }
    initLambda = () => {
        console.log("Base initLambda");
    }
}
class Derived extends Base {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }
    init() {
        console.log("Derived init");
    }
    initLambda = () => {
        //let x = this.prop;
        console.log("Derived initLambda");
    }
}
```

Output:
Derived init
Base initLambda

Comment: Why does it need to be a "lambda"?

Comment: @NitzanTomer - I typically use the "instance arrow function" when the function needs access to "_this", to ensure I always have the correct context.

Comment: I don't believe the arrow function are going to do what you think. The `this` in them is going to be the `this` of whatever surrounding environment happens to be. You say * This method is called from the base constructor, and needs access to instance properties, so it needs to be a lambda function, so "this" is "_this"*, but I don't think you understand how derived classes. A method called in the constructor will always invoke the version on the base class if it exists, even when it is defined in the normal way.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Well, you can't have that.
There's [an issue that was opened](https://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/2491) but it was closed as "by design".

You should use regular methods:

```
class Base {
    protected prop = null;

    constructor() {
        this.init();
        this.initLambda();
    }

    init() {
        console.log("Base init");
    }

    initLambda() {
        console.log("Base initLambda");
    }
}

class Derived extends Base {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    init() {
        console.log("Derived init");
    }

    initLambda() {
        console.log("Derived initLambda");
    }
}
```

And then it will work.

As for keeping the right `this`, you can always pass a call to the method as an arrow function:

```
doit() {
    setTimeout(() => this.init(), 1);
}
```

Or use the [Function.prototype.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) function:

```
setTimeout(this.init.bind(this));
```

Also, the `_this` thing that the typescript compiler produces is just a hack to polyfil the arrow functions for ES5, but if you change the target to ES6 then it won't use it.

---

#### Edit:

You can save the bound methods as members:

```
class Base {
    ...
    public boundInit: () => void;

    constructor() {
        ...
        this.boundInit = this.initLambda.bind(this);
        setTimeout(this.boundInit, 500);
    }

...
```

With that, when I do `new Derived()` this is what I get:

> Derived init
>   Derived initLambda // after 200 millis

Comment: Along these lines, I thought this might work in the base constructor but did not - let x = () => this.initLambda(); x();

Comment: You can save bound functions like that as members and then use those. What do you by "not working"?

Comment: Did not call the derived method - that is what I was trying to do.

Comment: Check my revised answer

Comment: 'There's an issue that was opened but it was closed as "by design".' - the link is broken

Comment: @benshabatnoam right, well, this post is pretty old... I have no idea if they recreated this issue (or what it was) in github.

Comment: Well, can't see the sense in lambda functions of javascript at all.. They just make things more complex and limited... I now have a 3rd party DI service where the methods for some reason are organized as a lambda. So I cannot override its functionality to replace DI service with mine.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your lambda is a property.

When compiled to javascript, the `Base`class becomes

```
var Base = (function () {
    function Base() {
        this.prop = null;
        this.initLambda = function () {
            console.log("Base initLambda");
        };
        this.init();
        this.initLambda();
    }
    Base.prototype.init = function () {
        console.log("Base init");
    };
    return Base;
}());
```

As you can see `initLambda` is defined *inside* the constructor of `Base`, so there is no way you can override that.

Calling `super()` calls the `Base` constructor which defines the `this.initLambda` with the code in `Base` and runs it. Hence your result.

View on [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20Base%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20protected%20prop%20%3D%20null%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.init()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.initLambda()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20init()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log(%22Base%20init%22)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20initLambda%20%3D%20()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log(%22Base%20initLambda%22)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D)

Comment: I guess you could say you CAN override it, but it's not overridden until instantiated.

Comment: @user210757 yes. Basically, don't call `this.initLambda()` in the Base constructor, override it in `Derived` then call it from `Derived`

Answer (score 0):

Try using using a [getter](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#getters--setters) property.

i.E.

```
get initLambda() {
    return () => {
        console.log("...");
    }
}
```

In such way that the whole code looks like that:

```
class Base {
    protected prop = null;
    constructor() {
        this.init();
        this.initLambda();
    }
    init() {
        console.log("Base init");
    }
    get initLambda() {
        return () => {
            console.log("Base initLambda");
        }
    }
}
class Derived extends Base {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }
    init() {
        console.log("Derived init");
    }
    get initLambda() {
        return () => {
            //let x = this.prop;
            console.log("Derived initLambda");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `Base` class can be a 3rd party library - so you can't change its signatures. Thus, this approach is not universal.