# In Angular, How to call virtual method from class than inherits inside parent class?

Tags: angular, typescript, inheritance, extends, virtual-functions

I have two components that inherits of one base class :

1. Class **ChildA** extends **Base**
2. Class **ChildB** extends **Base**

To factorize some method, I would like to call the foo() from Childs in OnChanges() from **Base**
like this :

```
export abstract class Base implements OnChanges{
    ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
        this.foo();
    }
    foo(): void{
       throw("Error, it shouldn't be instantiated. Override this method.");
    }
}

export class ChildA extends Base{
    ...
    foo(): void{
         alert("This is the correct method which has to be called !");
    }
}
```

The result is :

> Error, it shouldn't be instantiated. Override this method.

Not :

> This is the correct method which has to be called !

Someone has an idea ?

Comment: Well, you just did. What is the problem? I would just make the foo() method abstract, to force subclasses to override it.

Comment: Sorry, in my case, the foo() method called is one from Base :/

Comment: Can you create a plunker that reproduces the issue. This similar code works fine: https://plnkr.co/edit/ttK0TZ6MHwACi5YAZDa2?p=preview

Comment: Same here: http://plnkr.co/edit/Z4OTXKkE0NQ4YUM4erpI?p=preview. (check the console). Can't reproduce.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I could compare with your results. I was confused, I just had to remove Base in "declarations" and delete @Component for this class as well. For Base, I did a mixt between an abstract class and a parent component ^^.

Comment: Which version of `tsc` is involved? Has it compiled the latest version of your file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeScript - how to inherit class and override lambda method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38640961/typescript-how-to-inherit-class-and-override-lambda-method)