# Invoking derived class new method from base class - Is there an equivalent of 'virtual class' in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

I am looking for a clean option to realize a functionality similar to C++ [virtual classes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_class)

Simplified use-case:
I am developing a mobile app that can potentially connect to multiple backend 'camera recording systems'. My app will have multiple 'views' like 'Events', 'Montage' etc. I don't want to litter each view with backend specific code.

To achieve this, I've done the following:

```
export  class CameraServiceProvider {
  getCameras(credentials?): Promise <Camera[]> {
    throw constants.NOT_IMPLEMENTED;
  }
// ... other methods
}
```

`CameraService Provider` is the base class. There are `adapters` that extend this class and provide their own vendor specific implementations. For example:

```
export class ZmCameraServiceProvider extends CameraServiceProvider {
  getCameras(credentials): Promise <Camera[]> { 
  // specific code for this camera provider backend
   }
}
```

In my `app.component.ts` I do:

```
@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app.html',
  providers: [
    {provide: CameraServiceProvider, useClass: ZmCameraServiceProvider},

  ]
})
```

**This setup now allows me to instantiate and use `CameraServiceProvider` in my main app.** In future, if I need to change to a different system managing cameras, all I need to do is develop a new `whateverCameraServiceProvider` and modify my `useClass` - the rest of my app code remains untouched.

There is one issue: For every new method `mynewFoo()` I add to `ZmCameraServiceProvider` I must declare that method in `CameraServiceProvider` as well, otherwise the compiler complains that `mynewFoo()` doesn't exist.

I suppose one way to think of it is, if a method exists in `ZmCameraServiceProvider` that doesn't exist in `CameraServiceProvider` and I am calling it in my main app, I am breaking my own design goal of backend independence - I suppose that is right. I'm still curious if this can be achieved - that is, use a base class to invoke a  new method in a derived class

That is why I'm looking for some construct similar to a virtual class.

Comment: That doesn't sound like an issue, really - if it isn't defined in the public API defined in `CameraServiceProvider`, it shouldn't be being called on things that could be any one of its subclasses.

Comment: Correct - I added exactly that statement in my post as you typed :) - Curious anyway

Comment: Then no, that can't be achieved, for exactly that reason. The compiler won't let you invoke methods that may not be there, you'd have to include an assertion to a type that did have it, which may then fail at runtime (in which case why bother using TS?)

Comment: I also assume Typescript doesn't allow for a virtual class concept then as I linked to in my original post?

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html

Comment: Thanks I did go through that link. I suppose I meant to ask 'is there another way to achieve functionality similar to a virtual class' - but I think you've answered it - 'not in typescript' (or 'not in typescript without breaking the safeguards it offers'). Thanks.

Comment: I doubt that any language lets you declare methods in a subclass and has those methods automatically accessible from the base class.  That's not a virtual class, it's upside-down inheritance.  Do you have a working example in some other language you can share?   

Or just pass `ZmCameraServiceProvider` as your `provide` if you care about its specific functionality.  What am I missing here?

Comment: I was about to roll my eyes by saying 'of course it exists' and point you to the example of this in wikipedia for C++ (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_class) but then I realized this example was wrong - C++ doesn't have virtual classes (only functions and not the way I specified it) - so you're right @jcalz and john too, it was a quest for a solution to a non-problem :-p

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeScript - how to inherit class and override lambda method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38640961/typescript-how-to-inherit-class-and-override-lambda-method)