# Template method pattern in typescript

Tags: typescript, angular5

Is there any way to implement something like the template method pattern in typescript? I tried to do it but the problem is that the methods that are overridden in the child class are not called, but the methods from the base class instead.
Example:

```
class Parent {
    doSomething(){
        doSomethingElse(); //or this.doSomethingElse();
    }

    protected doSomethingElse(){
    }
}

class Child extends Parent{
    protected doSomethingElse(){
    }
}
```

What I want here is to create a Child instance and call the `doSomething();` method, but in this method the `doSomethingElse();` method from the Child class should be called instead of the one from the Parent class.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38640961/typescript-how-to-inherit-class-and-override-lambda-method

Comment: It's unclear what the problem is. Existing Child is supposed to do what you want. *doSomethingElse(); //or this.doSomethingElse()* - so is it `doSomethingElse()` or `this.doSomethingElse()`?

Comment: when calling `childInstance.doSomething()` it will call `doSomethingElse()` from the Parent class, and I want to call the one from the Child class.
It works perfectly in C#, but here is different

Comment: @estus: "`doSomethingElse(); //or this.doSomethingElse()`- so is it doSomethingElse() or this.doSomethingElse()" - both of them have the same result

Comment: @MadalinSisu They cannot have same result. this.doSomethingElse is class method that exists in your code. And doSomethingElse is some function that will cause an error because it isn't defined. Please, provide http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve that can replicate the problem. The code you've posted should work as expected, at least with this.doSomethingElse , http://plnkr.co/edit/c7YiAfvsBBCPzJacGDEM?p=preview

Comment: [There](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20Parent%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20doSomething()%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.doSomethingElse()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20protected%20doSomethingElse()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20alert(%22Base%22)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Aclass%20Child%20extends%20Parent%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20protected%20doSomethingElse()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20alert(%22Child%22)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Avar%20obj%20%3D%20new%20Child()%3B%0D%0Aobj.doSomething()%3B) everything is working. What do you mean?